# What is the pythonic way to print a list of numbers over the length of the list?

Tags: python

```
fruits = ["apple", "orange", "banana"]

for i in range(len(fruits)):
    print(i+1)

# output: 1 2 3
```

Is there a better way of doing this rather than `range(len())` ?

Comment: What do you intend to you with these numbers ? If you clarify, you will get better answers.

Comment: `range(len(...))` isn't bad here. But if you need the value too you should use `enumerate`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the enumerate built-in fuction:

```
fruits = ["apple", "orange", "banana"]

for i, _ in enumerate(fruits, 1): # _ is used in python for non used vars
    print(i)

# output: 1 2 3
```

Otherwhise, if you use range you should use `range(1,len(fruits)+1)` to avoid the +1 inside the loop